# How to set current store in loop

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, filter

Setting current store in loop is not working for me. I want get product collection in loop filtered by store. Here is how i am doing it:

```
$allStores = Mage::app()->getStores();

foreach ($allStores as $_eachStoreId => $val)
{
    $_storeId = Mage::app()->getStore($_eachStoreId)->getId();
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($_storeId);

    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addStoreFilter();

}
```

It always returning collection of first store id in loop.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "It always returning collection of first store id in loop." what does that mean? How did you check it? What did you expect?

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
$allStores = Mage::app()->getStores();

foreach ($allStores as $_eachStoreId => $val) 
{
   $_storeId = Mage::app()->getStore($_eachStoreId)->getId();
   $collection = "";
   $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->setStoreId($_storeId);
}
```

A product does not "belong to a store". If you want to exclude it from display in a store view, the most common method is to set its visibility in this store scope to "Not visible individually"

Comment: nope!! Not working. Still receiving same response. collection gets loaded with products of first store only both times.

Comment: i have updated answer check it

Comment: Still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may think that setCurrentStore() works only once (the 1st time only) during one PHP session. The next time, starting with the 2nd call, it appears to do nothing.

There's a bug in the Magento core. Objects, which are dependent on the selected store, are created only once during one php session and then used from a cache. Here goes the fix:

app/Mage.php

```
public static function getResourceSingleton($modelClass = '', array $arguments = array())
{
    $registryKey = '_resource_singleton/'.$modelClass;
    // { Added by Andrew Usachov
    $object = self::registry($registryKey);
    if ($object && method_exists($object, 'getStoreId') && $object->getStoreId() != self::app()->getStore()->getId())
    {
        self::unregister($registryKey);
    }
    // } Added by Andrew Usachov
    if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
        self::register($registryKey, self::getResourceModel($modelClass, $arguments));
    }
    return self::registry($registryKey);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work either, it still only ever pulls the data from the default store view and products from all websites.